# Input cache ao atualizar a pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

É possível manter as informações digitadas no Input ao atualizar a pagina somente usando front end?

```css
input {
border-color: blue;
padding:5px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Manter este texto com ID" id="cache">
<input type="text" value="Não manter sem ID">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim! Você pode usar **localStorage**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        input {
            border-color: blue;
            padding:5px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <input type="text" id="cache">
    <input type="text">

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var cache = localStorage.getItem("cache");
    $('#cache').val(cache);
    $('#cache').keyup(function() {
      localStorage.setItem("cache", this.value);
    });
</script>
</html>
```